# Ranking groups based on size

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Sample Data:

```
id cluster
1 3
2 3
3 3
4 3
5 1
6 1
7 2
8 2
9 2
10 4
11 4
12 5
13 6
```

What I would like to do is replace the largest cluster id with `0` and the second largest with `1` and so on and so forth. Output would be as shown below.

```
id cluster
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 2
6 2
7 1
8 1
9 1
10 3
11 3
12 4
13 5
```

I'm not quite sure where to start with this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The objective is to relabel groups defined in the `'cluster'` column by the corresponding rank of that group's total value count within the column.  We'll break this down into several steps:

1. Integer factorization.  Find an integer representation where each unique value in the column gets its own integer.  We'll start with zero.
2. We then need the counts of each of these unique values.
3. We need to rank the unique values by their counts.
4. We assign the ranks back to the positions of the original column.

---

**Approach 1**
Using Numpy's `numpy.unique` + `argsort`

**TL;DR**

```
u, i, c = np.unique(
    df.cluster.values,
    return_inverse=True,
    return_counts=True
)
(-c).argsort()[i]
```

Turns out, `numpy.unique` performs the task of integer factorization and counting values in one go.  In the process, we get unique values as well, but we don't really need those.  Also, the integer factorization isn't obvious.  That's because per the `numpy.unique` function, the return value we're looking for is called the `inverse`.  It's called the inverse because it was intended to act as a way to get back the original array given the array of unique values.  So if we let

```
u, i, c = np.unique(
    df.cluster.values,
    return_inverse=True,
    return_couns=True
)
```

You'll see `i` looks like:

```
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5])
```

And if we did `u[i]` we get back the original `df.cluster.values`

```
array([3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6])
```

But we are going to use it as integer factorization.

Next, we need the counts `c`

```
array([2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1])
```

I'm going to propose the use of `argsort` but it's confusing.  So I'll try to show it:

```
np.row_stack([c, (-c).argsort()])

array([[2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5]])
```

What `argsort` does in general is to place the top spot (position 0), the position to draw from in the originating array.

```
#            position 2
#            is best
#                |
#                v
# array([[2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1],
#        [2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5]])
#         ^
#         |
#     top spot
#     from
#     position 2

#        position 1
#        goes to
#        pen-ultimate spot
#            |
#            v
# array([[2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1],
#        [2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5]])
#            ^
#            |
#        pen-ultimate spot
#        from
#        position 1
```

What this allows us to do is to slice this `argsort` result with our integer factorization to arrive at a remapping of the ranks.

```
#     i is
#        [2 2 2 2 0 0 1 1 1 3 3 4 5]

#     (-c).argsort() is 
#        [2 1 0 3 4 5]

# argsort
# slice
#      \   / This is our integer factorization
#       a i
#     [[0 2]  <-- 0 is second position in argsort
#      [0 2]  <-- 0 is second position in argsort
#      [0 2]  <-- 0 is second position in argsort
#      [0 2]  <-- 0 is second position in argsort
#      [2 0]  <-- 2 is zeroth position in argsort
#      [2 0]  <-- 2 is zeroth position in argsort
#      [1 1]  <-- 1 is first position in argsort
#      [1 1]  <-- 1 is first position in argsort
#      [1 1]  <-- 1 is first position in argsort
#      [3 3]  <-- 3 is third position in argsort
#      [3 3]  <-- 3 is third position in argsort
#      [4 4]  <-- 4 is fourth position in argsort
#      [5 5]] <-- 5 is fifth position in argsort
```

We can then drop it into the column with `pd.DataFrame.assign`

```
u, i, c = np.unique(
    df.cluster.values,
    return_inverse=True,
    return_counts=True
)
df.assign(cluster=(-c).argsort()[i])

    id  cluster
0    1        0
1    2        0
2    3        0
3    4        0
4    5        2
5    6        2
6    7        1
7    8        1
8    9        1
9   10        3
10  11        3
11  12        4
12  13        5
```

---

**Approach 2**
I'm going to leverage the same concepts.  However, I'll use Pandas `pandas.factorize` to get integer factorization with `numpy.bincount` to count values.  The reason to use this approach is because Numpy's `unique` actually sorts the values in the midst of factorizing and counting.  `pandas.factorize` does not.  For larger data sets, big oh is our friend as this remains `O(n)` while the Numpy approach is `O(nlogn)`.

```
i, u = pd.factorize(df.cluster.values)
c = np.bincount(i)
df.assign(cluster=(-c).argsort()[i])

    id  cluster
0    1        0
1    2        0
2    3        0
3    4        0
4    5        2
5    6        2
6    7        1
7    8        1
8    9        1
9   10        3
10  11        3
11  12        4
12  13        5
```

Comment: I like your method better.  +1

Comment: Thanks for your response. I made the mistake of oversimplifying my sample data set. In my actual dataset, I'll have multiple clusters of the same size and they won't be increasing by 1. Some clusters will be of size 14 and others will be size 10. Please see my updates

Comment: @madsthaks Do you want them to increase or not? Because with my answer, they won't increase.

Comment: Yes, I'd want them to increase. If they don't they it'll be as if they belong to the same cluster which would be incorrect.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I put together a solution below. Not the cleanest but it gets the job done. Maybe you can suggest something more efficient.

Comment: @madsthaks Updated my answer. (:

Answer (score 3):

You can use `groupby`, `transform`, and `rank`:

```
df['cluster'] = df.groupby('cluster').transform('count')\
                  .rank(ascending=False, method='dense')\
                  .sub(1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   id  cluster
0   1        0
1   2        0
2   3        0
3   4        0
4   5        2
5   6        2
6   7        1
7   8        1
8   9        1
9  10        3
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `category` and `value_counts`

```
df.cluster.map((-df.cluster.value_counts()).astype('category').cat.codes
)
Out[151]: 
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    2
5    2
6    1
7    1
8    1
9    3
Name: cluster, dtype: int8
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the cleanest solution but it does work. Feel free to suggest improvements:

```
valueCounts = df.groupby('cluster')['cluster'].count()
valueCounts_sorted = df.sort_values(ascending=False)

for i in valueCounts_sorted.index.values:
    print (i)
    temp = df[df.cluster == i]
    temp["random"] = count
    idx = temp.index.values
    df.loc[idx, "cluster"] = temp.random.values

    count += 1
```